# How to set and get the value of Data Bind Gridview Combobox Column in C#

Tags: c#

I have a data grid view with combo box column in it, i have bind that column to datatable like this:

```
 ((grdItems.Columns[1]) as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn).DataSource = dt;
 ((grdItems.Columns[1]) as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn).DisplayMember = "LocationName";
 ((grdItems.Columns[1]) as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn).ValueMember = "Id";
```

now i can get the selected value like this:

```
var value = grdItems.Rows[0][1].Value;
```

but the issue is, when i manually add the rows in the gridview (without binding the grid), i cant get the value of the combobox cell.
i am adding rows like this:

```
grdItems.Rows.Add(1, 1, "Some Value");
```

when i use 
**var value = grdItems.Rows[0][1].Value;**
this method to get the value, i returns me the text of the cell not the value i.e **1** in this case.

How can i solve this issue? since i want the value of the cell in case of adding rows manually, as well as data-bind rows.

Answer (score 0):

Am assuming that by manually adding rows you mean from the UI , so one way to get the value of the newly added row is to use an `event handler` for the `events` raised when you add an row. You may use one of the following 
1) `RowsAdded` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowsadded(v=vs.110).aspx 2) `RowPrePaint` - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowprepaint(v=vs.110).aspx - not used this much but is also an option

```
this.myGridView.RowsAdded += new DataGridViewRowsAddedEventHandler(myGridView_RowsAdded);

 private void myGridView_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{
    var newRow = this.myGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex];
}
```

Edit: Based on the actual requirement stated in the comments - actual requirement being retrieving the newly added row's cell value (Id) corresponding to the combox box column on button save clicked event

Assuming you have bound the combo box to a data source itself , meaning, your

```
 combobox.DataSource=someList
```

so what you can do is write a linq query

```
 someList.Where( v=>v.Text.Equals("row.Cells[1].Value")).FirstOrDefault().Id
```

Comment: i dont want the value of the column when the new row is added. i want the value later on looping through all the rows in the grid and get the value of each cell including the combo box cell

Comment: you could do that by keeping the newly added the rows in memory and revisit it later , however am _not sure what you mean by later?_ later when any specific event like hitting save button ?

Comment: yes, by hitting Save button.. when i click on save button i have done this: foreach(DataGridViewRow row in grdView.Rows)                                        { var val = row.Cells[1].Value; } However this gives me the Text of the cell, not its value that i have bind to it

Comment: oh I see.. i am assuming you have bound the combo box to a data source itself , meaning, your `combobox.DataSource=someList`? so what you can do is write a linq query `somelist.where( v=>v.Text.Equals("row.Cells[1].Value" ).FirstOrDefault().Id`to retrieve the value corresponding to the text - does that make sense?